# Upper bound on iterations of a decreasing function

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following decreasing function:

$$n_0 =n$$
$$n_{i+1} = n_i \left ( 1 - \frac{4}{\ln n_i + 2} \right)$$

Given $1 < k \ll n$ what is a good upper bound for the number of iterations needed to reach a value $n_i < k$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence is decreasing, so as long as $\ln n_i > 2$:
$$
\begin{align*}
n_i &\le n_0 \\
\frac{4}{\ln n_i + 2} &\ge \frac{4}{\ln n_0 + 2} \\
1 - \frac{4}{\ln n_i + 2} &\le 1 - \frac{4}{\ln n_0 + 2} \\
n_i &\le n_0 \left( 1 - \frac{4}{\ln n_0 + 2} \right)^i
\end{align*}
$$
So the (easy) solution for $i$ to:
$$
\frac{k}{n_0} = \left( 1 - \frac{4}{\ln n_0 + 2} \right)^i
$$
gives an upper bound. Dunno if "good"...